# How to run command line python tool in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, command-line

I am new to Heroku platform. My requirement is to run a python command line tool from Heroku. I am not sure if this can be done directly as applications over there are the web applications with other mandatory files such as procfile etc. The approach I am thinking to take is to create a web app that could call the python script. But next question comes up is how to call python script which allows passing arguments to it too. And do I need to deploy the python tool and web app separately? Please guide me with the approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that python scripts are executed automatically, use [Heroku Sheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). It will count towards your dyno usage and is free.

[image]

Depending on how long and complex your tasks are/will be in the future, you will need a custom clock process, which is not free.

If you want to execute a script yourself, then cd into your project, login with heroku and use `heroku run python`.

Comment: No, I can't use the scheduler. I run the tool on the command line as 'python tool.py -d "domain.txt" -o "outputfile.txt"'. I want the same capability on Heroku. Can I run the above command using Heroku run python?